# move uiviewcontrollers to the back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have an app I am building that needs to have uiview or uiviewcontroller remain on top. The best way to describe it is via an example. Imagine a website where a floating menu is always on top in the center of the screen. As you navigate the new pages load underneath the navigation bar.

What I am looking for is a way to keep a custom UIView on top (i.e. front most uiview or front most uiview controller) but slide new viewcontroller's underneath it. The design won't work with a container view, as when the app first loads the menubar (or custom floating menu view in my case) is over a ContainerViewcontroller. This containerView hold several containerviews.

Any suggestions or help at all would be appreciated. I pretty sure it isn't possible, but what I would like to do is use a navigationbar/ stack and push view controllers on, but always underneath the menu. Or use a addChildViewController, but underneath a top most viewcontroller (i.e. my menu).

UPDATE: Can I do this?

```
self.newviewcontroller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -200, self.view.bounds.size.width, 96);
self.newviewcontroller.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:self.newviewcontroller.view];
[self addChildViewController:self.newviewcontroller];
[self.newviewcontroller didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:mainFloatingMenu];

// THen animate the new view onto the screen
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                      delay:0.3
                    options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut)
                 animations:^{
                     self.newviewcontroller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,   self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     // do notta
                 }];
```

Comment: Might be you can add a view in the app delegate on the window and all view behind your custom menu view .as it seem very much same to the floating circle button in iPhone.Whenever I want to display some overlay on top of everything else, I just add it on top of the Application Window directly:

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:someView]

Comment: you might try ECSlidingViewController, maybe this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view insertSubview:mainFloatingMenu aboveSubview:mainView];
```

or

```
[self.view insertSubview:floatingMenu atIndex:20000];
```